# google protocol buffer encode string

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a code snippet that use protocol buffer but in the writeTo method string values is not encoded

After writing a output stream i can read the string values

```
business::Company company;
company.set_name("Example Ltd.");
company.set_url("http://www.example.com");

 // 1st employee
 {
   business::Employee *employee = company.add_employee();
   employee->set_first_name("John");
   employee->set_last_name("Doe");
   employee->set_email("john.doe@example.com");
 }           

fstream output("company.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
company.SerializeToOstream(&output);
```

Comment: Protobuf uses UTF-8 for string encoding (as do many serializers); if you look at the data as a text file, yes the text contents will be readable (surrounded by some odd random characters that are the headers, length markers, etc). This is normal and expected, and doesn't mean that it isn't being encoded correctly. Is this what you are talking about? Serialization/encoding is not encryption.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes. Is there any way to change the encoding from UTF-8 to ascii ?

Comment: If the string data is in the ASCII range (0-127), then UTF-8 and ASCII produce the exact same output, so: already done. If the string data is **not** in the ASCII range, then writing it as ASCII would guarantee that you would corrupt the data and result in values that cannot be reliably decoded - so that would be an extraordinarily bad idea. The data shown in the example is all in the ASCII range, so: already done. But to be explicit, no there's no way to choose the encoding manually: string data is encoded as UTF-8, and *that's a good thing*.